# How can i add sort order for featured products in opencart?

Tags: php, sorting, opencart

Hi does anyone know if there is a way to choose which of your featured products show first? How can i sort products in featured module? like newest to oldest..
This is the code for module . How can i set the sort order for products ?

```
    $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

    $data['text_tax'] = $this->language->get('text_tax');

    $data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');
    $data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');
    $data['button_compare'] = $this->language->get('button_compare');

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $this->load->model('tool/image');

    $data['products'] = array();

    if (!$setting['limit']) {
        $setting['limit'] = 4;
    }

    if (!empty($setting['product'])) {
        $products = array_slice($setting['product'], 0, (int)$setting['limit']);

        foreach ($products as $product_id) {
            $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

            if ($product_info) {
                if ($product_info['image']) {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $setting['width'], $setting['height']);
                } else {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $setting['width'], $setting['height']);
                }

                if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                } else {
                    $price = false;
                }

                if ((float)$product_info['special']) {
                    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                } else {
                    $special = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                    $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$product_info['special'] ? $product_info['special'] : $product_info['price']);
                } else {
                    $tax = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                    $rating = $product_info['rating'];
                } else {
                    $rating = false;
                }

                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $product_info['product_id'],
                    'thumb'       => $image,
                    'name'        => $product_info['name'],
                    'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'special'     => $special,
                    'tax'         => $tax,
                    'rating'      => $rating,
                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_info['product_id'])
                );
            }
        }
    }

    if ($data['products']) {
        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/featured.tpl')) {
            return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/featured.tpl', $data);
        } else {
            return $this->load->view('default/template/module/featured.tpl', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have any code, what have you tried, did you have lunch today, how far is the moon? Might need a little more information mate.

Comment: i found some code on internet but i dont know which file and which line i should add it.  i found this "ORDER BY p.date_added DESC"  but i dont know how or is it correct.

Comment: Mate that is of not help as well, you need to have a read around and get a better understanding of the code you downloaded.  If we cant see the code we cant help you.

Comment: im using default opencart theme and im not using any extension or extra modules , this featured module is default opencart module and you can add products in it . Newly added products shows on end of list and old ones on top. I just want to make it opposite , older added ones on end of list and news on top. I  dont understand what you want to see. Its standart Opencart 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every product in Opencart has a "Sort order" field on "data" tab, you can fill it when you add or edit a product:

[image: Opencart Sort order field for product]

Go to this file:

```
catalog/controller/module/featured.php
```

add these to line to products array

```
'sort_order' => $product_info['sort_order'],
'date_added' => $product_info['date_added']
```

and use `array_multisort` as bellow:

```
$temp_array = array();
foreach ($data['products'] as $key => $row){
    $temp_array[$key] = $row['sort_order'];
}
array_multisort($temp_array, SORT_ASC, $data['products']);
```

insert above code just before `if ($data['products']) {`

Here is full code:

```
<?php
class ControllerModuleFeatured extends Controller {
    public function index($setting) {
        $this->load->language('module/featured');

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $data['text_tax'] = $this->language->get('text_tax');

        $data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');
        $data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');
        $data['button_compare'] = $this->language->get('button_compare');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $data['products'] = array();

        if (!$setting['limit']) {
            $setting['limit'] = 4;
        }

        if (!empty($setting['product'])) {
            $products = array_slice($setting['product'], 0, (int)$setting['limit']);

            foreach ($products as $product_id) {
                $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

                if ($product_info) {
                    if ($product_info['image']) {
                        $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $setting['width'], $setting['height']);
                    } else {
                        $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $setting['width'], $setting['height']);
                    }

                    if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                        $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                    } else {
                        $price = false;
                    }

                    if ((float)$product_info['special']) {
                        $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                    } else {
                        $special = false;
                    }

                    if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                        $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$product_info['special'] ? $product_info['special'] : $product_info['price']);
                    } else {
                        $tax = false;
                    }

                    if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                        $rating = $product_info['rating'];
                    } else {
                        $rating = false;
                    }

                    $data['products'][] = array(
                        'product_id'  => $product_info['product_id'],
                        'thumb'       => $image,
                        'name'        => $product_info['name'],
                        'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
                        'price'       => $price,
                        'special'     => $special,
                        'tax'         => $tax,
                        'rating'      => $rating,
                        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_info['product_id']),
                        // Add 'sort_order' and 'date_added' to products array
                        'sort_order' => $product_info['sort_order'],
                        'date_added' => $product_info['date_added']
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        // Create a temporary array
        $temp_array = array();
        foreach ($data['products'] as $key => $row){
            // You can use 'date_added' or 'sort_order' or 'price' or ...
            $temp_array[$key] = $row['date_added'];
        }
        // You can use SORT_ASC or SORT_DESC
        array_multisort($temp_array, SORT_ASC, $data['products']);


        if ($data['products']) {
            if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/featured.tpl')) {
                return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/featured.tpl', $data);
            } else {
                return $this->load->view('default/template/module/featured.tpl', $data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested this on Opencart 2.1.0.1,
Hope this help you.

Comment: Still Products which is added old  on top of the Featured  and new ones at bottom. I copy full code still same . Maybe its file with same name in admin folder

Comment: It worked now. I changed SORT_ASC to desc and voila! Thank you very much.